# How to know assets:precompile done on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know assets:precompile done or not on rake.
Currently, I check existence of `public/assets`.

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.css')
```

`find_asset` does not work in this case.

Comment: What are you achieving with that check?

Comment: I only run my rake task after assets:precompile. I know I can hook with  `Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].enhance`. But I want to write a code as independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this task](https://gist.github.com/subelsky/5078466) by `subelsky` to check if assets were precompiled:

```
namespace :assets do
  task :check do
    root_dir = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"..","..")
    assets_last_modified_at  = Dir["#{root_dir}/app/assets/**/**"].map { |p| File.mtime(p) }.sort.last
    assets_last_compiled_at =  Dir["#{root_dir}/public/assets/**/**"].map { |p| File.mtime(p) }.sort.last

    if assets_last_modified_at > assets_last_compiled_at
      fail "Assets need to precompiled; last asset modified at #{assets_last_modified_at}"
    end
  end
end
```

And then you can add this task to your task's dependencies:

```
task :mine => 'assets:check'
  ...
end
```

Comment: You are welcome! Consider also upvoting my question if you like the recommendation :)